# Load image dynamically with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jhipster

I am currently developing a **Ionic** app which uses **angularJs**. I also have a **Jhipster** made REST web service provider application running on web which provides data to my app.

What I currently do is, get the complete (text + image data) JSON with REST API call of jhipster. Text data includes id, name, address etc information of peoples and image data is the picture of people.

What I wish to do is load the images on load i.e. get fire the API call for text data and after the text data is rendered on page then call every image separately.

I already have separate API ready for text data and a another API to get single image according to id.

No here is my problem I want a way to fire my API call in `< img >` tag. After the list is rendered the directive/service associated with `< img >` will take the `people.id` of user and pass it to function which will then fire my API call getting image, bring the response (image)  and bind it to `< img >`.

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-avatar"
         ng-repeat="item in peoples ">

        <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.name}} Photo" err-src="img/people.png">

        <h2> {{item.firstName}} </h2>
        <span>   {{item.emailId}} </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change things a little bit to make this work. For example, instead of binding the data like you are doing it now, just change it to be a function which returns the whole thing in one go.

Something like : `<img ng-src="{{getMyData(yourID)}}" >`

then inside the getMyData function you do what you need, you fire the db call and return what you need. You can apply an ng-cloak as well, as the call will take a while to execute and get your data back.

```
$scope.getMyData = function(id)
        {
            //api work
            //create return string
            return 'the whole thing'
        }
```